# Swipe and click compability in Web/Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swipe

-I have a little problem with a swipe effect (ScrollLeft) and the "onclick" functionality.

-So what i actually want to achieve is when you scroll with your touchpad verticaly on a image (actually i will have like 2 images in a container) you will have the second image, same thing will happen with the click on one of my two buttons (Left or Right).

-My problem here is that i tried with two states to differentiate when i'm on my second image or when i'm on my first image.
So here is my loop function that will help me to "swipe" my image with my touchpad:

```
var s = 0; var pas = 10; var max = widthImg1; var state1 = 0; var stateImg = "front";


            function loop() {
                var bL = document.getElementById('imgButtonLeft');
                var bR = document.getElementById('imgButtonRight');
                if (s != max) {
                    s = wrapImage1.scrollLeft;
                    wrapImage1.scrollLeft += pas;
                    if (state1 == 0) {
                        console.log("First");
                        $("#backImg").addClass('select');
                        $("#frontImg").removeClass('select');

                        $('.imgTitleFront').hide();
                        $('.imgTitleBack').show();

                        bL.style.opacity = "1.0";
                        bR.style.opacity = "0.5";
                    }
                    if (state1 == 1) {
                        console.log("Second");
                        $("#frontImg").addClass('select');
                        $("#backImg").removeClass('select');

                        $('.imgTitleBack').hide();
                        $('.imgTitleFront').show();

                        bL.style.opacity = "0.5";
                        bR.style.opacity = "1.0";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Three");
                    pas = pas * -1;
                    if (state1 == 0) {
                        console.log("Four");
                        state1 = 1;
                    }
                    else if (state1 == 1) {
                        console.log("Five");
                        state1 = 0;
                    }
                    if (max == widthImg1) {
                        console.log("Six");
                        max = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Seven");
                        max = widthImg1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="wrapHidden" id="co">
            <div class="wrapImage" id="wrapImage1" onscroll="loop()">
                <div class="wrapBigSize" id="wrapBig">
                    <p class="imgButton left" id="imgButtonLeft" onclick="puceTransition(true)"></p>
                    <img class="myImage" id="myImageFront" src="imgFront">
                    <p class="imgButton right" id="imgButtonRight" onclick="puceTransition(false)"></p>
                    <img class="myImage second" id="myImageBack" src="imgBack">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my "onclick" function :

```
function puceTransition(front) {
if (front) {
    if (stateImg == "back") {
        stateImg = "front";
        state1 = 0;
        loop();
    }
} else {
    if (stateImg == "front") {
        stateImg = "back";
        state1 = 1;
        loop();
    }
}
```

}

So with that codes, my problem is that I think my code don't really know which state is on and I don't really know why.

Comment: You really need to minimise all this - only a part of it is relevant to your question

Comment: Is it better now? I wanted to be really clear sorry.